Angular 18: Multiple select components with a ng-container share same observable dropdown list
I have a page with four dropdown lists. All four will have same choices.

Can I have all four components share same Observable?
How do I bind component variable to dropdown in ng-template.

data.service.ts
export class DataService {
  public getRefs(): Observable<string[]> {
    return of(['Ed Hochuli', 'Jerome Boger', 'Walk Anderson', 'Mike Carey']);
  }
}

app.component.ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  onField1: string;
  onField2: string;
  tvRef: string;
  fourthRef: string;

  refList$: Observable<String[]>;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refList$ = this.dataService.getRefs();
  }

  onItemSelected(ref: string) {
    console.log('onItemSelected');
  }
}

app.component.html
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="umpireSelectTemplate"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ controlName: 'onField1', label: 'On field 1' }"
/>
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="umpireSelectTemplate"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ controlName: 'onField2', label: 'On field 2' }"
/>
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="umpireSelectTemplate"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ controlName: 'tvRef', label: 'TV Ref' }"
/>
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="umpireSelectTemplate"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ controlName: 'fourthRef', label: '4th Ref' }"
/>

<ng-template
  #umpireSelectTemplate
  let-controlName="controlName"
  let-label="label"
>
  <div>
    <label id="row">{{ label }}:</label>

    <div id="row">
      <select
        class="form-control"
        name="{{ controlName }}"
        [(ngModel)]="onField1"
        formControlName="{{ controlName }}"
        (change)="onItemSelected($event)"
      >
        <option *ngFor="let ref of refList$ | async" [ngValue]="ref">
          {{ ref }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>

Stackbliz project is available
